# How to serialize to json array?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to serialize the following to a simple array of strings *not* of objects.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '["Developer", "Designer"]'

SELECT x.position
FROM (
    SELECT position
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (position nvarchar(50) '$')
) x
FOR JSON PATH
```

When I run the above I get: `[{position: "Developer"}, {position: "Designer}]`

But I want: `["Developer", "Designer"]`

How would I do that?

Comment: So you want your output string exactly the same as the input string? Then why not just `SELECT @Json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with "FOR JSON".
So back to string operations:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '["Developer", "Designer"]'

SELECT '["'+STRING_AGG( STRING_ESCAPE(x.position, 'json'),'", "') + '"]'
FROM (
    SELECT position 
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (position nvarchar(50) '$')
) x
```

Comment: Worth noting that `string_agg` is available only on 2017 or higher (where as `for json` is available for version 2016 as well). Still a good answer, though.

Answer (score -1):

Try declaring your json like this...

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{{"position": "Developer"}, {"position": "Designer"}}'
```

hth,

```
-n
```

Comment: what? This  doesn't answer the question at all.